# Unable to have a change in the LayoutParams of Android Gallery item be reflected in the view

Tags: android, gallery, invalidation, margins, layoutparams

I'm using the Android Gallery in SDK 2.3.3.  I need the margin to be wider for the selected item.  I keep a reference of the "last" selected item so when a new selection is made, I can modify the margin in the layout of the newly selected item as well as the previously selected item.  I have tried invalidating the view items concerned but can't seem to trigger the gallery items to be "refreshed".  Any help on how to make the change in margins affect the gallery would be greatly appreciated.

I'm happy to clarify any point, if necessary.

Thanks,
  Yuan

```
private class MySelectListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int unselected_margin_left = 1;
    private static final int unselected_margin_right = 1;
    private static final int selected_margin_left = 15;
    private static final int selected_margin_right = 15;

    private LinearLayout currWrapper = null;
    private LinearLayout lastWrapper = null;
    private Context ctx;

    public MySelectListener(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        // This LinearLayout is a wrapper for the gallery items
        currWrapper = (LinearLayout)(v.findViewById(R.id.unconf_order_item_layout_wrapper));

        // Reset the margins of the view that was selected
        try {
            if (lastWrapper != null) {
                setMargins(lastWrapper, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception clear) {
        }

        // Set the "wider" margins for the selected item
        try {
            setMargins(currWrapper, true);
        } catch (Exception animate) {
        }

        lastWrapper = currWrapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    private void setMargins(LinearLayout view, boolean selected) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
        if (selected) {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "setting selected margins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            layoutParams.setMargins(selected_margin_left, 0, selected_margin_right, 0);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "setting unselected margins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            layoutParams.setMargins(unselected_margin_left, 0, unselected_margin_right, 0);
        }
    }

}
```